# hide all keyboards android [with ads banner]

Tags: java, android, android-layout, google-play-services, ads

i created an application where i have an inputText and the input type is deciaml numbers.
When i Click on this input i have the right keyboard displayed and once i press on ok, i get automatically the normal keyboard:

[image: Screenshots of the application]

Here's the code for the layout file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="@color/whiteSmoke"
tools:context="com.habchi.soldecalculator.MainActivity">

<!-- Floating Solde Buttons -->

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:gravity="bottom">
    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_id">
    </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

I have to say that i don't have this problem when i delete the ads banner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found an answer. Hade to add android:imeOptions="actionDone" to the edittext

Answer (score 0):

Just curious, would you try adding `android:focusable="false"` to your AdView XML? I'm wondering if the keyboard is coming up because the AdView is able to gain app focus.

Comment: Tried your answer but it didn't worked! Thanks anyway :)

Comment: @Habchi no worries, seems like you got it figured out!